# Pyspark on EMR: How can I call udf() within an egg without breaking Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, amazon-emr, egg

I'm seeing a problem in Pyspark on EMR where Spark processing hangs if I have imported an egg that calls `pyspark.sql.functions.udf()`.

I'm on an EMR cluster running emr-5.3.1 with Spark 2.1.0, Zeppelin 0.6.2, Ganglia 3.7.2.

I would like to be able to create a library of UDFs that can be used with various jobs.

In a Zeppelin notebook I am running:

```py
%pyspark
sc.addPyFile("s3://your_s3_path/my_egg-0.1-py2.7.egg")
from my_egg import *

obj = MyClass(sqlContext)
obj.do_map()
```

The code in my_egg is:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def my_scalar_func(input):
    return input

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

# This is the line that causes the whole thing to hang. Uncomment it to reproduce the issue
udf_my_scalar_func = udf(my_scalar_func, StringType())

def my_map_func(row):
    return row

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, sqlContext):
        self.sqlContext = sqlContext
        self.raw_data = [{"id": 1, "name": "first"}]
        self.schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), False), StructField("name", StringType(), False)])

    def do_map(self):
        print "Creating data frame"
        self.df = self.sqlContext.createDataFrame(self.raw_data, self.schema)
        print "Data frame: {0}".format(self.df.collect())
        self.rdd = self.df.rdd.map(my_map_func)
        # The collect() call hangs if the UDF line above is uncommented
        print "Mapped RDD: {0}".format(self.rdd.collect())
```

Processing hangs during the last line of `do_map()` (where the rdd.map() and collect() are executed). I have waited up to 3 hours before killing the job.

If I comment out the line defining `udf_my_scalar_func` then the whole thing executes in less than a second.

Note that the `udf_my_scalar_func` and `my_scalar_func` are never called and don't really have anything to do with the code that is actually executed.

I don't know enough about Spark and Pyspark internals to figure out why this is happening. How can it be explained? And is there a way to define a UDF within an egg? Or is there another way to create a library of UDFs that are easily accessible to Pyspark jobs submitted to the cluster?

I've created a Github repo with a full set of steps to reproduce this issue, including creating an EMR cluster, at https://github.com/ss-emonsen/emr_udf_egg.

Comment: So if you need fast workaround, force `SparkSession` / `SQLContext` (not `SparkContext`) initialization before you import `udf` (any dummy action like listing tables from catalog should do).